# Tkinter recal value from a looped list of entries

Tags: loops, tkinter

I don't understand how to recall the value from the entry grid, I got the array of the entries

```py
import tkinter as tk
import sys

class Main:
    # >>>>> Init <<<<<
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.entries = []

    # >>>>> Menu <<<<<
    def menu(self):
        self.master.geometry("400x150")
        self.master.title("Score Calculator")
        main_label = tk.Label(self.master, text="Score program")
        main_button1 = tk.Button(self.master, text="Enter score", command=self.judge_score)
        main_button2 = tk.Button(self.master, text="Calculate results", command=self.calculate_results)
        main_button3 = tk.Button(self.master, text="Save and Quit", command=self.save_results)
        main_button4 = tk.Button(self.master, text="Show current results", command=self.show_result)
        main_label.pack()
        main_button1.pack()
        main_button2.pack()
        main_button3.pack()
        main_button4.pack()

    # >>>>> Score <<<<<
    def score(self):
        window = tk.Tk()
        # >>> The 5*6 grid <<<
        for x in range(6):
            for i in range(5):
                entry = tk.Entry(window, width=4).grid(column=i, row=x)
                self.entries.append(entry)
```

So this part has the score grid that needs to be able to output a value when the value is typed in I will add the button for confirming results but for now I need to be able to recall

```py
root = tk.Tk()
app = Main(root)
app.menu()
root.mainloop()

print(app.entries)
```

Comment: just call `self.entries[i].get()`. The trick is to be able to identify the correct index `i`. This can be done in many ways, but the logic is upto you

Comment: Also, do not use multiple instances of `tk.Tk()`. Rather use `Top Level`